# Visual Studio: How do I import a module from a static library?

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022

I've successfully created and built a static library in Visual Studio. It's main output is a module named "ciflib".

I have created a new project in which I want to use that library, and I can't get the modules contained within to be recognised.

I've set the "Additional Library Directories" to point to the place I have the `ciflib.lib` file saved. I've set the "Additional Dependencies" (under Linker->Input) to point to `ciflib.lib`.

When I `import ciflib;` in my new project, Visual Studio can't find my module.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Visual Studio 22 and /std:c++20

edit:

The two errors of import are:

C2230 could not find module 'ciflib'

E3275 could not find module file for module "ciflib"

I also get the red squiggly line under 'ciflib' in 'import ciflib;', so noone can find it.

Comment: I usually see problems finding files/libraries in 1 of 2 ways.  **1**, the compiler/linker can find it but the IDE can't.  When this happens, the code builds fine but I get red in VS saying it's not found.  **2**, visual studio can find it but the compiler/linker cannot.  

**Which problem are you seeing?** do you have any errors?

Comment: What is the .h file?  Or are you using the modules feature?  If so, what have you done to the original project to ensure it is suitable as a module?  Are you exporting it?  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170) link for module support.

Comment: @J'e I'm seeing both errors.

Comment: @KevinAnderson It's a module. I `export module ciflib;`

Comment: @masher are you doing this from the link: _To enable support for Standard Library modules, compile with `/experimental:module` and `/std:c++latest`._  You may need it for your modules too (not sure).